# Differentiable Complex Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ be differentiable for all $z = x + iy$. If $$v(x,y) = x + xy + y^2 - x^2$$ for all $(x,y)$, find $u(x,y)$ and express $f(z)$ in terms of $z$. I'm lost because it never says what $f(z)$ is explicitly equal to, just that it equals $u + iv$ so I'm not sure how to start.

On a side note, how do you format questions in Latex? I couldn't find the option.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial. Enclose mathematical expressions in $$

Comment: Since $f$ is complex differentiable, $u$ and $v$ have to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann differential equations. Write them down, and integrate them. The solution is unique up to a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,y)=x+2y$$and that$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)=2x-y-1.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I know what to do next but I just want to make sure. If you integrate partial of u w.r.t x over x, then you can u(x,y) plus some function of y, then that function of y is just partial of u w.r.t y?

Comment: It's someting like that. If you integrate $u$ with respect to $x$, you get that $u(x,y)=\frac12x^2+2xy+C(y)$ and so on.

Comment: I ended up getting my answer but I'm lost on the last part. I have that u(x,y) = 1/2(x^2 - y^2) + 2xy - y, but I'm not sure how to convert that in terms of z if z = x + iy

Comment: You have$$f(x+yi)=\frac12(x^2-y^2)+2xy-y+(x+xy+y^2-x^2)i=\frac12(x+yi)^2-i(x+yi)^2+i(x+yi)$$and therefore$$f(z)=\left(\frac12-i\right)z^2+iz.$$

Comment: Thanks so much!!